# Эмулятор среды macintosh под debian

Tags: linux, apple, эмулятор

Быть может задам странный вопрос, но можно ли в debian установить эмулятор среды macintosh? (по типу wine -- эмулятор среды windows)

Comment: Наверное, только через установку OS X в виртуальной машине, например, в VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только используя виртуальную машину: Virtual Box или VMWare. Но учтите, что работа с OS X в виртуальной машине это, как правило, мучение.